# Error on getting values from previous activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm having problems on getting the values from my previous activity. I am creating a quiz app that uses colored buttons as choices. Basically, you just have to pick the button that the instruction says. Here's the code:

```
public class EasyMode2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Intent g = getIntent(); // get values from EasyMode1Activity.java
    public int score = g.getIntExtra("score", 5);
    public final int questionTotal = 5;
    public int question = g.getIntExtra("questions", 5);
    public int questionsAnswered = g.getIntExtra("questionsAnswered", 5);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_easy_mode2);

        Button btn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        Button btn5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        Button btn6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);

        btn4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                question++;
                TextView scoreText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtScore2);
                scoreText.setText(scoreText.getText() + "" +score);

                toResults(view);
            }
        });

        btn5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                question++;
                TextView scoreText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtScore2);
                scoreText.setText(scoreText.getText() + "" +score);

                toResults(view);
            }
        });

        btn6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                question++;
                score++;
                TextView scoreText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtScore2);
                scoreText.setText(scoreText.getText() + "" +score);
                questionsAnswered++;
                toResults(view);
            }
        });

        TextView questionTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtquestion_number2);
        questionTxt.setText(questionTxt.getText() + " " +question+ " of " +questionTotal);

        final Chronometer timer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer2);
        timer.start();

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    public void toResults (View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent (this, ResultsActivity.class);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt("score", score); // store the score
        b.putInt("questionsAnswered", questionsAnswered);
        b.putInt("question", question);
        i.putExtras(b); // put your score to your next intent
        startActivity(i);
    }

}
```

Also, I tried running the app on my phone. It crashed. The previous activity (EasyModeActivity1 - they have similar code, with the exception that it has the initial values) works but once I click any of the buttons in that activity, it is supposed to go to EasyModeActivity2 but it would crash instead.

Comment: can you provide the specific error log from your logcat?

Comment: Yes, please post the full logcat and highlight where the error occurs.

Comment: How do I post the logcat?

Answer (score 0):

Place these lines:

```
Intent g = getIntent(); // get values from EasyMode1Activity.java
public int score = g.getIntExtra("score", 5);
public final int questionTotal = 5;
public int question = g.getIntExtra("questions", 5);
public int questionsAnswered = g.getIntExtra("questionsAnswered", 5);
```

inside onCreate like this:

```
Intent g = getIntent(); // get values from EasyMode1Activity.java
if (g != null) {
    score = g.getIntExtra("score", 5);
    questionTotal = 5;
    question = g.getIntExtra("questions", 5);
    questionsAnswered = g.getIntExtra("questionsAnswered", 5);
}
```

just after this line:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_easy_mode2);
```

while passing :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DestinationActivity.class)
intent.putExtra("myStringKey", "My String value");//pass string
intent.putExtra("myBooleanKey", false);//pass boolean
intent.putExtra("myIntKey", 50);//pass integer
intent.putExtra("score", 50);
intent.putExtra("unanswered", 100);
intent.putExtra("questionsAnswered", 15);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: So do I put these in subsequent activities also? I added it below the btn instances and kept

`Intent g = getIntent(); // get values from EasyMode1Activity.java
public int score = g.getIntExtra("score", 5);
public final int questionTotal = 5;
public int question = g.getIntExtra("questions", 5);
public int questionsAnswered = g.getIntExtra("questionsAnswered", 5);`

on where they were. Btw, I ran the app again. It still crashed.

Comment: Yes you should do it for all activities. At the bottom of the screen in Android Studio, you will see some tabs like Terminal, Todo, Android Monitor, Version Control, just click on Android Monitor tab you will see the error log when the app crashes. Just copy that and paste it here in your question